# Is it necessary to use Media queries?

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries

I am really confusing about `media queries` although i am very new to this field.
I developed a website,its `width:1024px`.  Its working fine in all browsers.
Its not a mobile website,So is it necessary to use `media queries`.
I google it ,I got answer like , according to screen size we can use media queries (especially for mobile websites )

But i dont want to work my website in mobile,

**My question**

**Is it compulsory to use `media  queries`  when we developing a wesite**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no requirement of any kind that a web site should use media queries.

Moreover, just using media queries is useless. They are used to set different presentation styles for different viewports or devices. If you have no intention of ever considering the possibility that someone might view your page in a window narrower than 1024 pixels, I don’t see why you would even consider using media queries (at least for width issues, which are by far the most relevant in media queries).

The point is that media queries are essentially conditions in “if ... then ...” constructs. If you have just one alternative for the “then” part, the condition is of no use.

Answer (score 1):

essentially no,

If you prefer to work with multiple screen sizes then only the media queries need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Is it compulsory?  Its depend on you.

Users have certain expectations when viewing your site on everything from a desktop to a laptop to a netbook to a tablet to a handheld. They need a high level of  user experience satisfaction .For that you can use `Media queries`

`Media queries` are an excellent way to deliver different styles to different devices, providing the best experience for each type of user. A part of the CSS3 specification, media queries expand the role of the media attribute that controls how your styles are applied

Try this link,you will get a good idea about `media queries`

[When can I use CSS3 Media Queries?](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Thanks prash  ,your links are very usefull